# Nuget Versioning: Wildcard vs unspecified component

Tags: c#, nuget

Reading the [Nuget version documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning), I don't understand the difference between:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="ExamplePackage" Version="6.1" />
```

and:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="ExamplePackage" Version="6.1.*" />
```

If the actual package versions is `6.1.5`. It seems like both meet the requirement (`6.1.5` is greater than `6.1` and `6.1.0`). I am assuming for this purpose that missing components (such as the 3rd component in the first example above) is implied to be `0` for the purposes of version comparison.

Can someone explain the semantic differences, if any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If the actual package versions is 6.1.5. It seems like both meet the requirement [...]

Yes, they do.

> I am assuming for this purpose that missing components [...] is implied to be 0 for the purposes of version comparison.

Correct, `6.1` and `6.1.0` are the same.

> Can someone explain the semantic differences, if any?

In your first example, version `6.1` means that all package versions starting from `6.1.0` (inclusive) can be used, which implies `6.1.0`, `6.1.5`, but also `7.3.8-pre42`. Due to the [*Lowest Applicable Version*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution) rule, when there are multiple packages that match the criteria, the lowest version will be used.

The second example is different, it uses a *floating* notation, which means that `6.1.*` allows for all versions that start with `6.1`, but the **patch** and **pre-release** versions can be anything like `6.1.5`, `6.1.998` or `6.1.1-pre42`. Consequently, you exclude all versions below `6.1.0` and starting with `6.2.0` and above, also for pre-releases. Here, the [*Floating versions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution) rule applies, that restores the highest matching version.

In summary, both notations are not equivalent, the first represents an inclusive starting version, while the second only allows for a specific version with wildcards on the patch and prerelease number.

Comment: While this is mostly complete, in practice the difference between `6.1` and `6.1.*` is that the former will take the lowest matching version, while the latter will take the highest. In this example (6.1.0, and 6.1.5 respectively) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution

Comment: @pquest Thank you very much, I have added remarks about resolution.